# How is possible write this makefile?

Tags: eclipse, makefile, crypto++

I have these 3 commands that compile my program:

1. g++ -I/usr/include/cryptopp -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"AESBest.d" -MT"AESBest.d" -o "AESBest.o" "AESBest.cpp"
2. g++ -I/usr/include/cryptopp -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"main.d" -MT"main.d" -o "main.o" "main.cpp"
3. g++ -L/usr/include/cryptopp -o "Crypto"  AESBest.o main.o   -lcryptopp -lpthread

How is possible to create a makefile considering these 3 commands?

In Eclipse I receive output from the program in the shell, but in my bash, when I compile the bin file called "Crypto" and launch it, I have no output in my bash shell.
Why?

Comment: Consider moving your last two lines to a separate question with more comments and explanations.

Answer (score 2):

This will work:

```
all:
  g++ -I/usr/include/cryptopp -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"AESBest.d" -MT"AESBest.d" -o "AESBest.o" "AESBest.cpp"
  g++ -I/usr/include/cryptopp -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"main.d" -MT"main.d" -o "main.o" "main.cpp"
  g++ -L/usr/include/cryptopp -o "Crypto" AESBest.o main.o -lcryptopp -lpthread
```

And you can break it down a little like this:

```
AESBest.o:
  g++ -I/usr/include/cryptopp -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"AESBest.d" -MT"AESBest.d" -o "AESBest.o" "AESBest.cpp"

main.o:
  g++ -I/usr/include/cryptopp -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"main.d" -MT"main.d" -o "main.o" "main.cpp"

Crypto:
  g++ -L/usr/include/cryptopp -o "Crypto" AESBest.o main.o -lcryptopp -lpthread
```

And then simplify like this:

```
AESBest.o main.o: %.o : %.cpp
  g++ -I/usr/include/cryptopp -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF$*.d -MT$*.d -o $@ $<

Crypto: AESBest.o main.o
  g++ -L/usr/include/cryptopp -o $@ $^ -lcryptopp -lpthread
```